# Converting Access query with calculated columns to TSQL

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I'm trying to convert an INSERT TO Access query to a T-SQL `INSERT INTO` query. It contains several calculated columns. The query is supposed to take information from the GANV7 database on one server and input it into the view database on another server, which is why I've opted for the longer names below. Most of the formatting is complete but I can't clear the error on the line below.

The original code for the calculated columns:

```
Nz(GANV7_SORDERQ!QTYSTU_0-GANV7_SORDERQ!INVQTYSTU_0) AS SV_OQTY
```

What I've written so far:

```
,ISNULL([GANV7].[SORDERQ].[QTYSTU_0], 0) - ISNULL([GANV7].[SORDERQ].[INVQTYSTU_0],0) AS [sview].[SV_OQTY]
```

What I'm getting from SSMS:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 130
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I've typed the text out manually to rule out any hidden characters and I've checked the syntax and not found any issues. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your AS clause you need to escape the square brackets:

```
ISNULL([GANV7].[SORDERQ].[QTYSTU_0], 0) - ISNULL([GANV7].[SORDERQ].[INVQTYSTU_0],0) AS [[sview]].[SV_OQTY]]]
```